# Arduino cannot light up led based on analog input variable

Tags: c++, arduino

I cant make arduino output high using a variable for example I declare this above my function

```
int pin;  
pinMode(A1, OUTPUT);
```

Main function

```
 if(id ==2){
 pin = A1;
 ledlight();}
 if(id==3){
  pin  =A2; 
 ledlight();}
```

And after that i call this to light up my LED

```
  void ledlight(){
  if (temp < 27 ) {

  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);  
   }
   }
```

Surprisingly the led does not light up, when i replace it with A1 the led lighted up ,what is the problem ?

Comment: Why did you declare `pin` twice?

Comment: one is global, one is inside the loop function, different id have different assignment of pin either A!, A2  or A3

Comment: Why is your indentation all over the place? Where is your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Where is your declaration of `temp`? How can you be sure that it _is_ less than 27?

Comment: And where do you read the value of the analog pin into temp?

Answer (score 0):

use Serial to debug your program

output every variable(id temp pin), then you will find out the answer

here is the example of Serial

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(3, digitalRead(2));
  int n = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.print("analogRead from A0:");
  Serial.print(n);
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(100);
}
```